# Python pandas calculate distances between dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes.
Once the regular dataframe:

**df**

```
Datum                   
...
2014-12-30 23:00:00 
2014-12-30 23:15:00 
2014-12-30 23:30:00 
2014-12-30 23:45:00 
2014-12-31 00:00:00 
...
2015-01-01 00:00:00 
2015-01-02 00:00:00 
2015-01-03 00:00:00 
2015-01-04 00:00:00 
2015-01-04 00:00:00 
2015-01-05 00:00:00 
...
```

and a Dataframe that includes the holiday dates. If, for example, the daterange of **DF** is 2014-2015, then DF-Holiday has the holidays of 2014 and 2015:

**DFHolidays**

```
           DATE
NAME    
Neujahr 2014-01-01
Heilige Drei Könige 2014-01-06
Karfreitag  2014-04-18
Ostersonntag    2014-04-20
Ostermontag 2014-04-21
1. Mai  2014-05-01
...
Erster Weihnachtsfeiertag   2015-12-25
Zweiter Weihnachtsfeiertag  2015-12-26
...
```

Dataframe "DF" should now have a new column for each holiday, which calculates the distance in days to the holiday of his year for a given row.

example:

```
                        Neujahr Heilige Drei Könige    Karfreitag      ...
...
2014-01-01 23:00:00       0               value             value
2014-01-02 23:15:00       1               value             value
2014-01-03 23:30:00       2               value             value
2014-01-04 23:45:00       3               value             value
2014-01-05 00:00:00       4               value             value
...
```

i wrote following code.

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
def computeDiff(x,y):
    x = pd.to_datetime(x).date()
    print("x: ",x)
    mask = mask = (y.dt.year == x.year)
    y = y.loc[mask]
    y = y.get_value(0,0)
    print("y: ",y)
    y = pd.to_datetime(y).date()
    return (y - x).days

for holiday in list(DFHolidays.index):
    day = DFHolidays.loc[holiday, 'DATE']
    df[holiday] = df['Datum'].apply(computeDiff, args=(day,))
```

That works, but it is very slow. How could i solve this more elegantly?

**EDIT:** Full DFHolidays (in this example for just two years. Real datas are about 10+ Years.

```
    DATE
NAME    
Neujahr 2016-01-01
Karfreitag  2016-03-25
Ostersonntag    2016-03-27
Ostermontag 2016-03-28
1. Mai  2016-05-01
Christi Himmelfahrt 2016-05-05
Pfingstsonntag  2016-05-15
Pfingstmontag   2016-05-16
Tag der deutschen Einheit   2016-10-03
Erster Weihnachtsfeiertag   2016-12-25
Zweiter Weihnachtsfeiertag  2016-12-26
Neujahr 2017-01-01
Karfreitag  2017-04-14
Ostersonntag    2017-04-16
Ostermontag 2017-04-17
1. Mai  2017-05-01
Christi Himmelfahrt 2017-05-25
Pfingstsonntag  2017-06-04
Pfingstmontag   2017-06-05
Tag der deutschen Einheit   2017-10-03
Erster Weihnachtsfeiertag   2017-12-25
Zweiter Weihnachtsfeiertag  2017-12-26
```

Comment: What's with the trailing 0 on your datetimes?

Comment: Ignore it. Its the data from the column X. i deleted it :) @asongtoruin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2014-12-30 23:00:00','2014-12-30 23:15:00','2014-12-30 23:30:00','2014-12-30 23:45:00','2014-12-31 00:00:00']})

DFHolidays = pd.DataFrame({'NAME': ['Neujahr', 'Heilige Drei Könige', 'Karfreitag', 'Ostersonntag', 'Ostermontag', '1. Mai', 'Erster Weihnachtsfeiertag', 'Zweiter Weihnachtsfeiertag'],
                           'DATE': ['2014-01-01','2014-01-06','2014-04-18','2014-04-20','2014-04-21','2014-05-01','2015-12-25','2015-12-26']})

# Ensure all dates are actually dates
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
DFHolidays['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(DFHolidays['DATE'])
DFHolidays.set_index('NAME', inplace=True)

# Loop over each holiday, apply the calculation
for holiday_name, date in DFHolidays['DATE'].to_dict().items():
    df[holiday_name] = date - df['Date']
```

This returns, with the sample data given:

```
                 Date             Neujahr Heilige Drei Könige  \
0 2014-12-30 23:00:00 -364 days +01:00:00 -359 days +01:00:00   
1 2014-12-30 23:15:00 -364 days +00:45:00 -359 days +00:45:00   
2 2014-12-30 23:30:00 -364 days +00:30:00 -359 days +00:30:00   
3 2014-12-30 23:45:00 -364 days +00:15:00 -359 days +00:15:00   
4 2014-12-31 00:00:00 -364 days +00:00:00 -359 days +00:00:00   

           Karfreitag        Ostersonntag         Ostermontag  \
0 -257 days +01:00:00 -255 days +01:00:00 -254 days +01:00:00   
1 -257 days +00:45:00 -255 days +00:45:00 -254 days +00:45:00   
2 -257 days +00:30:00 -255 days +00:30:00 -254 days +00:30:00   
3 -257 days +00:15:00 -255 days +00:15:00 -254 days +00:15:00   
4 -257 days +00:00:00 -255 days +00:00:00 -254 days +00:00:00   

               1. Mai Erster Weihnachtsfeiertag Zweiter Weihnachtsfeiertag  
0 -244 days +01:00:00         359 days 01:00:00          360 days 01:00:00  
1 -244 days +00:45:00         359 days 00:45:00          360 days 00:45:00  
2 -244 days +00:30:00         359 days 00:30:00          360 days 00:30:00  
3 -244 days +00:15:00         359 days 00:15:00          360 days 00:15:00  
4 -244 days +00:00:00         359 days 00:00:00          360 days 00:00:00
```

---

### With changed sample data

Understanding that the year of the data is important, we could do the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2016-02-15 23:00:00','2016-03-05 23:15:00','2016-12-30 23:30:00','2017-08-10 23:45:00','2017-09-01 00:00:00']})

DFHolidays = pd.DataFrame({'NAME': ['Neujahr','Karfreitag','Ostersonntag', 'Ostermontag', '1. Mai','Christi Himmelfahrt','Pfingstsonntag','Pfingstmontag', 'Tag der deutschen Einheit', 'Erster Weihnachtsfeiertag', 'Zweiter Weihnachtsfeiertag','Neujahr','Karfreitag','Ostersonntag',  'Ostermontag','1. Mai','Christi Himmelfahrt','Pfingstsonntag','Pfingstmontag', 'Tag der deutschen Einheit', 'Erster Weihnachtsfeiertag', 'Zweiter Weihnachtsfeiertag'],
                           'DATE': ['2016-01-01','2016-03-25','2016-03-27','2016-03-28','2016-05-01','2016-05-05','2016-05-15','2016-05-16','2016-10-03','2016-12-25','2016-12-26','2017-01-01','2017-04-14','2017-04-16','2017-04-17','2017-05-01','2017-05-25','2017-06-04','2017-06-05','2017-10-03','2017-12-25','2017-12-26']})

# Ensure all dates are actually dates
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
DFHolidays['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(DFHolidays['DATE'])

# Set up a year column in both dataframes ot join on shortly
DFHolidays['Year'] = DFHolidays['DATE'].dt.year
df['Year'] = df['Date'].dt.year

# Work out what all the holiday names are
holiday_names = DFHolidays['NAME'].unique()
DFHolidays = DFHolidays.pivot(index='Year', columns='NAME', values='DATE') \
                       .reset_index()

# Merge the frames
df = df.merge(DFHolidays, on='Year')

# Calculate the difference
for holiday in holiday_names:
    df[holiday] = df[holiday] - df['Date']
```

This gives us:

```
                 Date  Year              1. Mai Christi Himmelfahrt  \
0 2016-02-15 23:00:00  2016    75 days 01:00:00    79 days 01:00:00   
1 2016-03-05 23:15:00  2016    56 days 00:45:00    60 days 00:45:00   
2 2016-12-30 23:30:00  2016 -244 days +00:30:00 -240 days +00:30:00   
3 2017-08-10 23:45:00  2017 -102 days +00:15:00  -78 days +00:15:00   
4 2017-09-01 00:00:00  2017 -123 days +00:00:00  -99 days +00:00:00   

  Erster Weihnachtsfeiertag          Karfreitag             Neujahr  \
0         313 days 01:00:00    38 days 01:00:00  -46 days +01:00:00   
1         294 days 00:45:00    19 days 00:45:00  -65 days +00:45:00   
2         -6 days +00:30:00 -281 days +00:30:00 -365 days +00:30:00   
3         136 days 00:15:00 -119 days +00:15:00 -222 days +00:15:00   
4         115 days 00:00:00 -140 days +00:00:00 -243 days +00:00:00   

          Ostermontag        Ostersonntag       Pfingstmontag  \
0    41 days 01:00:00    40 days 01:00:00    90 days 01:00:00   
1    22 days 00:45:00    21 days 00:45:00    71 days 00:45:00   
2 -278 days +00:30:00 -279 days +00:30:00 -229 days +00:30:00   
3 -116 days +00:15:00 -117 days +00:15:00  -67 days +00:15:00   
4 -137 days +00:00:00 -138 days +00:00:00  -88 days +00:00:00   

       Pfingstsonntag Tag der deutschen Einheit Zweiter Weihnachtsfeiertag  
0    89 days 01:00:00         230 days 01:00:00          314 days 01:00:00  
1    70 days 00:45:00         211 days 00:45:00          295 days 00:45:00  
2 -230 days +00:30:00        -89 days +00:30:00          -5 days +00:30:00  
3  -68 days +00:15:00          53 days 00:15:00          137 days 00:15:00  
4  -89 days +00:00:00          32 days 00:00:00          116 days 00:00:00
```

To get just the number of days, change the last line to

```
df[holiday] = df[holiday].dt.date - df['Date'].dt.date
```

Comment: it is important to calculate the difference for a holiday which is in his Year. as you see computer_diff method checks if the year is the same. DFHoliday has as NAME muliple values. i'll  edit my question

Comment: As you see, the name entry is listed two times. one for 2016 and one for 2017.( in this example). in your example it calculates me the distance 366 days on date 2016-01-01  and Neujahr(new year). so in your example he takes the new year date for 2017 and not 2016